# play scala 2.4.3 redicrect not working

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying the [Reverse routing](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaRouting#Reverse-routing) sample code

Here are my routes

```
GET     /hello/:name      controllers.Application.hello(name)
GET     /bob             controllers.Application.helloBob
```

and my codes

```
 def helloBob = Action {
     Redirect(routes.Application.hello("Bob"))
     }

 def hello(name: String) = Action {
     Ok("Hello " + name + "!")
     }
```

I can get hello response

```
$ curl -v localhost:9001/hello/play
Hello play!
```

But, can't get "Bob" response after redirect?

```
$  curl -v localhost:9001/bob
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 9001 (#0)
> GET /bob HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9001
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
< Location: /hello/Bob
< Date: Fri, 18 Sep 2015 03:19:04 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path component of a URI is case sensitive. Check it.

try

```
curl -v localhost:9001/hello/Bob
```

**Update**

You code is correct (verified on my project) and you show the correct log - it prints 303 code. I think, you just need to say curl to follow redirect, like this

```
curl -L localhost:9000/bob
```

Comment: i've showed my code and it is not about case sensitive.

Comment: Well, you change it a lot. The reason is that I am thinking it's the Play print string "HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
< Location: /hello/Bob". You use "bob" before but now you are change it to "blob", are you sure there is no typo ? try to replace play answer as well on the new answer

Comment: definately it is typo error on the updated post. but, it was compile and running. the fundamental still there. the naming is diff. Why u dont vote? ok..ok..to minimize the confusion, i changed it to bob. u are not anwwering. curl -v localhost:9001/hello/Bob of course working and i showed it too.

Comment: well, I vote it app, but server answer is still the same - "HTTP/1.1 303 See Other < Location: /hello/Bob" can you print current answer that you have ?

Comment: nothing came up after * Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

Comment: please look my update. You code is correct and your command and response is correct - you just need to use -L flag with curl